# Counting many things in Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table of items each with a status and a category.  I'd like to produce an output page showing the number of items for each combination of status and category.

I'm passing a collection of the applicable fields to the blade. Leaving out many other fields.

```php
$items = item::all('id', 'status_id','category_id');
```

Now in the blade I'd like to iterate over all the possible status_id's and category_id's in $items to produce a table of counts.  There are about 8 possible statuses and 23 categories, so 180-200 count cells.  I'm expecting <10,000 items.

| Categories | Status A | Status B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category 1 | countif (A & 1) | countif (B & 1) |
| Category 2 | countif (A & 2) | countif (B & 2) |

The iteration is no problem, but how do I write the equivalent of countif()?

I suppose I could create an array of counts in the controller using lots of queries and pass that to the blade for display, but that seems even less efficient?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use SQL to do the grouping for you?

```php
$items = item::select('category_id', 'status_id')
             ->selectRaw('count(id) as count')
             ->groupBy('category_id', 'status_id')
             ->orderBy('category_id')
             ->orderBy('status_id')
             ->get();
```

This should give you an object somewhat like this:

```
[
    [
        'category_id' => 1,
        'status_id' => 1,
        'count' => 123,
    ],
    [
        'category_id' => 1,
        'status_id' => 2,
        'count' => 432,
    ],
    [
        'category_id' => 1,
        'status_id' => 3,
        'count' => 32,
    ],
    ...
    [
        'category_id' => 2,
        'status_id' => 1,
        'count' => 5,
    ],
    [
        'category_id' => 2,
        'status_id' => 2,
        'count' => 43,
    ],
    [
        'category_id' => 2,
        'status_id' => 3,
        'count' => 123,
    ],
    [
        'category_id' => 2,
        'status_id' => 4,
        'count' => 123,
    ],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Wow, that's really clever.  I don't think I would have come up with that.  However, I am struggling with how to work though this sparse array.  I expect that if I look for a combination that doesn't exist (count = 0), so not in the result, I'll get an exception.

Comment: If `category_id` and `status_id` are foreign keys, you need to join with their tables so the count gets all the possible combinations, even if the combination doesn't exist in the `Item` model. It's an easy enough query. If you edit those in I could give it a try. Using collection methods, you can also mold the array into whatever you want. If you have an idea of what you want the result to *look like*, post that as well.

Comment: I worked it out, thanks @IGP.  Since I'm iterating over all of the category_id's and status_id's to make my table, and your SQL array result has them nicely sorted, I just keep an index for $items and display $items[$index]->count when the sub-array id's match, then increment the index.  @if(isset($items[$index]) && $items[$index]->category_id == $category->id && $items[$index]->status_id == $status->id)